# JSP: Show search conditions and search results on a page

Tags: java, jsp

I'm a newbie JSP.

I want to built a page which contain a textbox and a Search button.
After I click Search button I want to remain search condition and show results below(not redirect to another page).

How do I built it?

Please give me an example.

Comment: atleast try it and ask only if you run into some issue.just to give you a head start you'll need ajax

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

In your search.jsp, write javascript function which gets triggered when button is clicked. Within this function call your search action(server side, may be a servlet) using AJAX, it will return you a promise aka callback function. In callback JS function, write logic to render your search results.